# Maximum heart rate increase/decrease while physically active

Tags: human-biology, physiology, cardiology

I'm a computer scientist and implementing a heart-rate monitor for physical exercise. While I try to improve my code, I stumbled over the question how fast the heart rate can change within a given time slot.

Let's say someone in rest has a pulse of 60bpm. If he now gets physically active and exploits himself, how much time will it take at least to reach his maximum pulse of (supposed) 200? How long will it take, after hitting that point to slow down his heart rate again?

Or to rephrase the question, so it fit's more to my specific code-problem.
How much can the pulse change (increase/decrease) within a small time-slot of, let's say 8 seconds.

Annotation:

Susan pointed out, that might be dependent on the trainings-state of each individual. If so, what is (might be) the highest possible increase/decrease?
I suppose the pulse increase of a bad trained person might be faster then that of a well trained person, whereas the the decrease of the pulse should be way faster of that trained person.

Annotation 2:

The question was already posted here: [How quickly can the human heart rate rise and fall](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/5021/how-quickly-can-the-human-heart-rate-rise-and-fall).

But not really answered. The answer here says, the rate can change within one beat. But it does not say by how much it can change, which bothers me. Especially *how much it can change within a given period.*

Comment: Are you looking for a constant? To my understanding, this parameter is highly dependent on age and [training status](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18620464).

Comment: I think there will be too many variables for this to get a precise answer - if I were you I'd ask myself whether it is important to track the heart rate so precisely, if it's for exercise then sampling/recording the heart rate every 5 seconds or 10 seconds isn't going to make much difference to the data.